# looking for a correlation function for categorical + numerical datasets in matlab

Tags: categorical-data, correlation, matlab

I am looking for a function in Matlab that calculates the correlation coefficient of a data set that includes categorical + numerical data. I am quite surprised this isn't as straightforward as I hoped it would be.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A correlation between a categorical and a numerical feature makes no sense. One could take the conditional mean per categorical and then look for any effects. One could test these effects using an ANOVA.

Comment: A regression tree will allow you to "test" numericals and categoricals